# Update Query doesnt work asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm using the following code to update the data into DB.
There is no error message on console while debugging or on client screen, since parameters are correct. What could be wrong on this?

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conexion"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();

SqlCommand actualizar = new SqlCommand();
actualizar.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
actualizar.CommandText = "update Proveedores set proveedores.nombre=@nombre,proveedores.razon_social=@razon,proveedores.rubro =@rubro,proveedores.banco=@banco,proveedores.cuenta_corriente=@cuenta_corriente where proveedores.rut_empresa=@rut";

actualizar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rut",rut.ToString());
actualizar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre",Nombre.Text);
actualizar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@razon", Razon.Text);
actualizar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rubro",Rubro.Text);
actualizar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@banco",Banco.Text);
actualizar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuenta_corriente",Cuenta.Text);

actualizar.Connection = conn;
actualizar.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Added image on test

[image]

Comment: Impossible to tell as you haven't given enough information. But at a glance, why are you doing `rut.ToString()`? Is that really a string in your DB?

Comment: @JaliyaUdagedara There's nothing wrong with the original code.

Comment: You are handling your connections wrong. They implement [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) and you need to take special care in disposing them. This isn't the cause of your issue, but is definitely something you need to fix.

Comment: Also worth reading: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @DavidG i was testing if it's make any changes and the value "rut" is a varchar type on "DB". Also what kind of information is it needed ?

Comment: Have you tried that query in the database with that paramters? Perhaps the where condition do not return any row

Comment: I hope there are records that match where condition

Comment: when i try to use the query on DB, it actually works .So i dont know what's wrong on the c# code @animalitomaquina

Comment: @DavidG apologies, didn't read the query correctly. Can you try,
SqlCommand actualizar = conn.CreateCommand() and remove actualizar.Connection = conn; But technically what you have done is same as above. Next thing I can think of is for some reason your query doesn't get rows selected, any way you can run SQL profiler or something and look at the query being executed

Comment: What is the structure of the table? What values are in the mysterious variables you show in this code? What exactly isn't working, are you just getting no update at all? Have you profiled the database to see if this SQL is actually running? Etc. etc. etc...

Comment: Are you sure where proveedores.rut_empresa=@rut finds a record?

Comment: @KenTucker it does find a record on SqlServer.

Comment: @DavidG "rut" is supposed to be it's primary key and a varchar type, same as the other data (varchar). is there any problem with the structure?

Comment: Do you have access to profiler to check what is the query that is being generated?

Comment: Given that it's a string, how about invisible, non-printing characters, unicode issues (chars that look the same but are different), leading spaces, etc?

Comment: is this database a local database in the project or is it already on the server and you are connecting to it

Comment: @KenTucker the database is already on server, Added a screenshot as proof to check that the query works on the current database.

Comment: Next step then is to replace rut.tostring() with "1244" in your code, and see if that works

Comment: @peterG it doesnt work.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, have you checked the number of rows affected? It's not something crazy like the connectionstring is pointing to the wrong db is it?

Comment: @peterG it doesn't affect any row and still execute the query, maybe there is an error with the variable "rut" but i cant find it's error

Comment: OK try building a select query, perhaps by copy and paste your existing update query code and amending it, using the same where clause and parameter. This should return (at least) one row. Then try a select query with the string literal. And so on. At some point it's got to work, because it's the same as you are doing in SSMS. If not, then you have narrowed it down further.